# How does one create a HF tokenizer with only a fraction of the vocabulary but without changing the model?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I tried to create a smaller tokenizer:

```
def get_tokenizer_with_subset_of_vocab(tokenizer: GPT2Tokenizer, percentage_to_keep: float) -> GPT2Tokenizer:
    """ 
    Create a tokenizer with a fraction of the vocabulary.     
    """
    from copy import deepcopy
    tok = deepcopy(tokenizer)
    assert id(tok) != id(tokenizer), "The tokenizer is not a deep copy!"
    special_tokens = tok.all_special_tokens
    # to make sure there is always a token set no matter what
    tok.unk_token = "the"  # but "the" is hopefully common enough that it doesn't damage the semantics of the sentence too much, however, putting EOS or something else might screw up the semantics of the sentence

    # Calculate the number of tokens to keep
    total_tokens = len(tok)
    tokens_to_keep_count = int(total_tokens * percentage_to_keep)

    # Get all non-special tokens
    vocab = tok.get_vocab()
    all_tokens = list(vocab.keys())
    non_special_tokens = [token for token in all_tokens if token not in special_tokens]
    assert "the" in non_special_tokens, "The token 'the' is not in the non-special tokens!"

    # Randomly sample from non-special tokens
    random_sampled_tokens = random.sample(non_special_tokens, tokens_to_keep_count - len(special_tokens))

    # Combine special tokens with the randomly sampled tokens
    final_tokens_to_keep = set(special_tokens + random_sampled_tokens + ["the"])
    assert "the" in non_special_tokens, "The token 'the' is not in the non-special tokens!"
    assert tok.unk_token == "the", "The token 'the' is not the unknown token!"

    # Update the tokenizer's vocab
    new_vocab = {token: idx for token, idx in vocab.items() if token in final_tokens_to_keep}
    tok.vocab = new_vocab
    tok.ids_to_tokens = {v: k for k, v in vocab.items()}
    return tok
```

but the unit test doesn't work as expected but code looks right:

```
def _test0_does_hacky_fraction_tokenizer_work():
    # - have a tokenizer with only the special token "the", check everything is "the"
    text_seq: str = "the cat is nice"
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
    new_tokenizer = get_tokenizer_with_subset_of_vocab(tokenizer, 1/tokenizer.vocab_size) 
    # encode to tokens then decode to text
    tokens = new_tokenizer.encode(text_seq)
    llm_seq_txt: str = new_tokenizer.decode(tokens)
    assert llm_seq_txt == "the the the the", f'Error: {llm_seq_txt=}'
    # have a tokenizer with only the special token "the" and "cat", check the->the anything_else->the and cat->cat
    text_seq: str = "the cat is nice"
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
    new_tokenizer = get_tokenizer_with_subset_of_vocab(tokenizer, 1/tokenizer.vocab_size) 
    # encode to tokens then decode to text
    tokens = new_tokenizer.encode(text_seq)
    llm_seq_txt = new_tokenizer.decode(tokens)
    assert llm_seq_txt == "the cat the the", f'Error: {llm_seq_txt=}
```

why?

Error

```
Exception has occurred: AssertionError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
Error: llm_seq_txt='the cat is nice'
  File "/lfs/ampere9/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/embeddings/div_act_based.py", line 199, in _test0_does_hacky_fraction_tokenizer_work
    assert llm_seq_txt == "the the the the", f'Error: {llm_seq_txt=}'
  File "/lfs/ampere9/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/embeddings/div_act_based.py", line 620, in <module>
    _test0_does_hacky_fraction_tokenizer_work()
  File "/lfs/ampere9/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/lfs/ampere9/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main (Current frame)
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
AssertionError: Error: llm_seq_txt='the cat is nice'
```

https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-does-one-create-a-hf-tokenizer-with-only-a-fraction-of-the-vocabulary-but-without-changing-the-model/71418

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing stems from a misunderstanding of how tokenizers and their vocabularies work in conjunction with language models like GPT-2. When you modify the tokenizer's vocabulary, the expectation that encoding and decoding operations will map unknown words to a specific token (like "the") doesn't automatically hold. Let's address the problems in your approach and propose a solution.

**Understanding the Problem**

**Tokenizer's Behavior**: When the GPT-2 tokenizer encounters words that are not in its vocabulary, it breaks them down into smaller pieces (subwords or characters) that exist in its vocabulary. If you drastically reduce the vocabulary, most words will not be directly represented and will be decomposed into the smallest available units (like individual characters if those are still in the vocabulary).

**Decoding Process**: The decoding process attempts to reconstruct the original text from token IDs. If the tokenizer's vocabulary does not include a direct mapping for a specific token ID back to a larger piece of text (because you've removed most of the vocabulary), it will fall back to whatever representations are available, which might still include subwords or characters for basic punctuation, numbers, etc., that were not removed.

**The Role of Special Tokens**: Special tokens (like "the" in your case) have specific uses in language models (e.g., padding, unknown, start-of-sentence, end-of-sentence). Arbitrarily deciding that all unknown words map to "the" doesn't align with how tokenization and decoding inherently work. The tokenizer doesn't redirect all unknown tokens to a single known token during encoding or decoding unless explicitly programmed to do so in a very specific manner, which is not standard behavior.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**

If your goal is to create a tokenizer that simplifies input text by mapping unrecognized words to "the", you would need to handle this at a higher level than just adjusting the tokenizer's vocabulary. Here's a conceptual approach:

**Pre-process Input Text**: Before tokenization, replace all words not in a predefined list (your significantly reduced vocabulary) with "the". This requires you to manually check each word against your reduced vocabulary.

**Tokenization and Encoding**: After pre-processing the text, use the tokenizer to encode the text. Since you've already replaced unrecognized words with "the", the tokenizer will encode the text as you expect.

**Custom Tokenizer Modification**: If you want to automate the replacement within the tokenizer, you would need to customize the tokenizer's encode method to check each word against the reduced vocabulary and replace it with "the" if not found. This is more complex and requires a deep understanding of the tokenizer's internals.

**An example you can try:**

```
def preprocess_text(text, allowed_tokens):
    words = text.split()
    processed_words = [word if word in allowed_tokens else 'the' for word in words]
    return ' '.join(processed_words)

# Assuming 'allowed_tokens' is a list of tokens you've decided to keep
text = "the cat is nice"
processed_text = preprocess_text(text, allowed_tokens)
tokens = tokenizer.encode(processed_text)
llm_seq_txt = tokenizer.decode(tokens)
```